# Pointer addition and element size

Tags: c++, pointers

At: http://www.fredosaurus.com/notes-cpp/arrayptr/26arraysaspointers.html

Under: **Pointer addition and element size**

There is the following code:

```
// Assume sizeof(int) is 4.
int b[100];  // b is an array of 100 ints.
int* p;      // p is a a pointer to an int.
p = b;       // Assigns address of first element of b. Ie, &b[0]
p = p + 1;   // Adds 4 to p (4 == 1 * sizeof(int)). Ie, &b[1]
```

How did "p" in the last line become "4"?

Thanks.

Comment: Note that it isn't always 4. It is just that on most modern 32/64-bit systems sizeof(int) is 4. But on more exotic platforms it could be anything, hence "assume sizeof(int) is 4" comment.

Comment: Not really esoteric systems. I think Arduino processors have sizeof(int) is 2

Answer (score 29, accepted):

(I assume that you mean "1" in the last line, not "p")

Pointer arithmetic in both C and C++ is a *logical* addition, not a *numeric* addition.  Adding one to a pointer means "produce a pointer to the object that comes in memory right after this one," which means that the compiler automatically scales up whatever you're incrementing the pointer with by the size of the object being pointed at.  This prevents you from having a pointer into the middle of an object, or a misaligned pointer, or both.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When you say: "which means that the compiler automatically scales up whatever you're incrementing the pointer with by the size of the object being pointed at.", why the multiplication by the size? When e add "1" for example you mentioned that this means to scale the pointer to the object that comes in memory after this one. Isn't this sufficient? Why the multiplication by the size of the data type? Thanks.

Comment: @SWEngineer- My apologies, I wasn't being very clear.  The *pointer* doesn't get scaled.  The amount that the pointer gets incremented by is what gets incremented.  That way, writing `ptr + 1` means "the memory address of pointer, plus one times the size of the objects being pointed at."

Comment: That's fine, don't worry. Thanks for your clarification. A small thing here, why do you think that we have to multiply sizeof(datatype) by the increment number (i.e; 1)? Is it just how C++ is designed, or there is a logical reason here? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The comment in the code you post it explains it: addition of an integer x to a pointer increases the pointer's value by x multiplied by the sizeof the type it is pointing to.

This is convenient because it doesn't usually make sense to change the pointer in smaller increments - you wouldn't want it to point into the middle of one of the elements.

Comment: You should add that the resulting "4" value is just one of a myriad of random values that could have occured in that code sample. In other words: the integer value that is contained in the memory area where p points to is simply... undefined.

Answer (score 4):

because p is pointer to a type with size 4 bytes. `+` operator on pointers is actually pointer *shift*. compiler knows the size of pointed type and shifts it by appropriate value

if you change `int` to `short`, p will be shifted by 2 bytes