# Acccessing values of array using pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I know that `*(ptr + 1)` will give me the value stored at address `+1` to the  `ptr`. But i am not able to digest that how when using it in array will give me the value stored at next index location. For example:

```
int main() {
    int arr1[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    char arr2[5] = {'a','b','c','d','e'};
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        cout<<*(arr1 + i);
    cout<<endl;
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        cout<<*(arr2 + i);
    return(0);
}
```

I get that `sizeof(char)` is `1` so `arr1+1` should point to next index. But what about `arr2+1` how it will point to next index value? I think next index of `arr2` should be `+4` of the initial address of `arr2`.
Am i wrong somewhere?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ - pointer addition and element size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772932/c-pointer-addition-and-element-size)

Answer (score -1):

If you try out this sample program, it might give you an insight to your question:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
        int arr1[5]  = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        char arr2[5] = { 'a','b','c','d','e' };

        printf("Size of arr1: %d\n", sizeof arr1);
        printf("Size of arr2: %d\n", sizeof arr2);

        printf("Size of (int*): %d\n", sizeof (int*));
        printf("Size of (char*): %d\n", sizeof (char*));
}
```

You will notice that in the first case, you will get different sizes of `arr1` and `arr2`. This is to be expected as the two arrays are pointing to different data types.

However, in the second case, you will notice that the sizes of `(int*)` and `(char*)` are the same. This is where the answer to your question lies -- both `arr1` and `arr2` are sequences of pointers to the individual data items.

Even though `arr1` and `arr2` point to items of different types, they both are sequences of pointers of the same size. That's why incrementing both `arr1` and `arr2` by 1 point to their corresponding next item.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is plain wrong, as arrays are not sequences of pointers unless you specifically declared them as arrays of pointers. Instead, they are sequences of the objects themselves. Pointer arithmetic is simply automatically scaled up to the size of the object being pointed to.