# Regarding pointers

Tags: c, pointers

So I've been experimenting with pointers for a while and a few questions have come up. In the code below, first of all, when I print the memory addresses for each of:
pHours++ - pHours - pHours + sizeof(char), I get the following results:
1989086632 - 1989086636 - 1989086636.
Shouldn't the value of pHours++ be by 4 units (Btw, doesn't C normally allocate 1 byte instead of 4 for storing a char?) larger, instead of smaller, than pHours's value?
Moreover, why is pHours + sizeof(char)'s value the same as pHours's? In the code I've written below, it becomes clear that the addition of sizeof(char) does change the address at which the pointer points, since when I omit it in the function's last printing statement, I get a segmentation fault (*nHours holds no value).
Also, why do I get a segmentation fault when I write nHours++, but not when I do the same for skata (skata++) or pHours (pHours++)?
Oh, two more things. Visual Studio's compiler gives me an error for not initializing *nHours and *skata before using them, but using an online compiler I'm allowed to do so. Why is this a mandatory practice in VS?
Also, why is it preferrable to use the format string %p instead of %d for referring to memory addresses?
That's all for now. Thank you in advance! :)

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MinutesPerHour 60

void ConvertTimeToHM(int time, int *pHours, int *pMinutes);

int main()
{
    int time, hours, minutes;
    printf("Enter a time duration in minutes: ");
    scanf("%d", &time);
    ConvertTimeToHM(time, &hours, &minutes);
    printf("HH:MM format: %d:%02d\n", hours, minutes);
    return 0;
}

void ConvertTimeToHM(int time, int *pHours, int *pMinutes)
{
    *pHours = time / MinutesPerHour;
    int *nHours, *skata, *kHours;
    *pMinutes = time % MinutesPerHour;
    //nHours = pHours;
    //nHours++;
    skata++;
    printf("%d %d %d\n", pHours++, pHours, pHours + sizeof(char));
    skata = nHours + 3 * sizeof(char);
    *skata = 19;
    printf("%d\n", *(nHours + 3 * sizeof(char)));
}
```

Comment: These days, the words "experimenting with" and "pointers" in the same sentence always give me a chill...

Comment: Break up that printf: `printf("%d ", pHours++); printf("%d ", pHours); printf("%d\n", pHours + sizeof(char));`.  Now it's well-defined, and your results will make sense.

Comment: You should probably break the question up into smaller discrete questions and then research each smaller part. Your first question has been asked and answered many times before. For example, [Pointer addition and element size](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4772932/608639).

Comment: `skata` isn't initialized to point anywhere, so its results are just about guaranteed not to make sense.  Same for `nHours` and `kHours`.  But you don't need those extra pointers anyway.

Comment: Bottom line, as always: When using pointers, always know where they point, always initialize them to point somewhere well-defined.  Uninitialized pointers don't work.

Comment: It's preferable to use `%p` to print pointers because `%p` works, while `%d` doesn't.  Simple as that. :-)  (On many platforms these days, pointers are bigger than ints, so `%d` will only print part of your pointer, and the rest of the printf call tends to get screwed up, too.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are these constructs (using ++) undefined behavior in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-using-undefined-behavior-in-c)

Comment: Please what is the idea behind this: "*`skata = nHours + 3 * sizeof(char);`*"?

Comment: Properly initializing variables is *always* a "mandatory practice".  As you've discovered, though, different compilers have different degrees of fussiness when it comes to explicitly reminding you to follow the rules.

Comment: "*print the memory addresses for each of:
pHours++ - pHours - pHours + sizeof(char), I get the following results: 1989086632 - 1989086636 - 1989086636.
Shouldn't the value of pHours++ be*" the order in which arguments to a function call are evaluated is not defined. It seems that the 4th is evaluated 1st then the 2nd and finally the 3rd argument. At least move printing `pHours++`  to a separate call.

Comment: Using variables before initialising them invokes the infamous Undefined Behaviour. Anything can happen form then on.

Comment: @SteveSummit it's much safer to experiment with pointers these days than it was back before memory protection was common, when a data-write via an errant pointer could hose your filesystem driver (and thus your filesystem, destroying your source code along with it) :)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Well, yes, although there's some irony there.  The machine and OS where C was invented (and where, in fact, I first learned it) had full memory protection.  It was a significantly later generation of "personal" computers that thought they could get away without an MMU.  That choice (among others) may have helped advance the computing industry in terms of popularity, but handicapped it badly in terms of robustness and security.  (In some ways we've never recovered.)

Answer (score 0):

> Moreover, why is pHours + sizeof(char)'s value the same as pHours's?

Because you invoked *undefined behavior* in the `printf` statement by trying to update `pHours` *and* use its value in a computation without an intervening sequence point (also for using the wrong conversion specifier).  Function arguments are not guaranteed to be evaluated left to right, and the result of `++` is not guaranteed to be evaluated immediately.

Break that up into multiple statements and you should see a different result.

> Visual Studio's compiler gives me an error for not initializing *nHours and *skata before using them, but using an online compiler I'm allowed to do so. Why is this a mandatory practice in VS?

Compilers are required to issue diagnostics for syntax errors and constraint violations - beyond that, it’s up to the individual vendor.

> Also, why is it preferrable to use the format string %p instead of %d for referring to memory addresses?

For the same reason we use `%f` for doubles and `%s` for strings and `%c` for individual characters - because the language specification says so.  Pointers are not integers; though they may have an integral representation on many systems, that’s not guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

> Shouldn't the value of pHours++ be by 4 units

I'm not sure which book you're reading, but whatever it is, it's not working for you...

Given `int *p;`, `p+0` is equivalent to `&p[0]`, `p+1` is equivalent to `&p[1]`, and so on. `(p + 1) - (p + 0)` must be `1`, logically, but that `1` does not denote a `char`; it denotes an `int`, since the that's the type you're pointing at.

On the other hand, if you were to cast `pHours` to `char *` (or `void *`) before and after `pHours`, you *might* see something more along the lines of what you expect... but it *might* also be `1`, if `CHAR_BIT` is 32 for example.

> (Btw, doesn't C normally allocate 1 byte instead of 4 for storing a char?)

Yes, in C, a `char` *always* occupies exactly one byte, thus `sizeof (char)` is **always** `1`... *however* the bytes needn't be octets; you can obtain the number of bits in a byte using `CHAR_BIT`, which is required (by the C standard) to be at least 8, and has been values such as `16` and `32` for some systems, so...

> larger, instead of smaller, than pHours's value?

The value of `p++` is `p` before incrementation. The value of `++p` is `p` after incrementation.

> Moreover, why is pHours + sizeof(char)'s value the same as pHours's?

In the following code you invoke undefined behaviour, so you shouldn't read too much into it.

> ```
> printf("%d %d %d\n", pHours++, pHours, pHours + sizeof(char));
> ```

You need to be aware that the order of evaluation of arguments is unspecified, and so `pHours++` followed by `pHours` in the next argument is undefined behaviour (i.e. could cause unpredictable results including crashes, security compromise, etc)... also by telling `printf` to print an `int` value and then passing an `int *` value: that's also UB. You probably meant to write: `printf("%p", (void *) pHours++); printf("%p %p\n", pHours, pHours + sizeof (char));`.

> Also, why do I get a segmentation fault when I write nHours++, but not when I do the same for skata (skata++) or pHours (pHours++)?

Undefined behaviour doesn't mean *will produce a segmentation fault*; that would be a very much *defined* behaviour. Undefined behaviour means... okay let's start with undefined... lacking in definition... right? That means it has no meaning. What I'm trying to say here is that *the behaviour of your code has no meaning*. It's *allowed* to segfault, but not really *required* to.

This explains buffer overflows, which don't necessarily cause segfaults; they might go unnoticed for many years as the product functions routinely and nobody probes it, then a hacker notices a segfault that looks suspiciously buffer overflowish... and manages to penetrate your codebase... No, a segfault is certainly *not* required here... but neither is any logical behaviour.

Where are you getting your expectations from? I fear that you might not actually be *reading*, but *guessing*... Please tell me you're not *guessing*... It's not safe to learn C that way! Trust me; I've been there and done that, and you've picked up a few of the same misunderstandings I had. If I'm correct, and you're *not* reading a book, consider going out and finding yourself a copy of K&R2E. Remember to do the exercises.

---

> Visual Studio's compiler gives me an error for not initializing *nHours and *skata before using them, but using an online compiler I'm allowed to do so. Why is this a mandatory practice in VS?

Visual Studio is detecting the undefined behaviour which is use of an uninitialised value... and at that point, there are no requirements upon Visual Studio to follow the C standard, as you've stepped outside of the realms of C, so it's allowed to cease compilation at that point.

---

> Also, why is it preferrable to use the format string %p instead of %d for referring to memory addresses?

`%p` tells `printff` to expect a `void *` argument, which is important because `printff` needs to know that it's operating upon a `void *` argument... `%d` tells `printff` to expect an `int` argument... The two types have different usecases. Don't mix them. It's undefined behaviour if you pass the wrong type of argument.

Comment: "... so it's allowed to cease compilation at that point." It would also be perfectly valid to produce a program which moos at you through your sound card, for example... Undefined behaviour is behaviour that is undefined.